# How php can be connected with Apache Zeppelin

Tags: php, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Search Engine in php and I want to pass results value to Apache Zeppelin for Clustering or Classification with pyspark.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

How about using notebook api ([link here](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#run-a-paragraph-asynchronously))?
Look at the part about params.